# Django admin list_display short_description

Tags: django, admin, short

In django admin, If we define an element for list_display we can assign `short_description` for that field as

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('upper_case_name','age')

    def upper_case_name(self, obj):
        return ("%s %s" % (obj.first_name, obj.last_name)).upper()
    upper_case_name.short_description = 'Name'
```

But what if I would like to change short description of age field ?
I would like to show the header of `Age` field as `Person's Age` instead `Age`. Of course, I can write custom functions as `upper_case_name` for each field but it is a bad solution I think.

Could you suggest me any easy way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 2 model field options that provide descriptions to users: [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name) and [help_text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#help-text). Using verbose names seems to be suitable in your case.